# Wait For Socket Data Transmission

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I'm using a `DataOutputStream` to transmit data over the network like this:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, port);
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());

dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Stackoverflow");
// ...
System.exit(0);
```

If my application terminates too early, the transmission will be aborted and therefore fail since not all data has been sent yet at that point.

To fix this, I could manually wait for some time before terminating:

```
try
{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, this solution is bad. Are there some "best practice" ways of assuring that all data has been sent before terminating my application?

Edit:
I don't have access to the server code.

Comment: Adding sleeps in network code doesn't accomplish anything. As long as you close the socket properly, the data should arrive. Are you sure the problem isn't at the other end?

Comment: The problem may be at the other end indeed but there may be ways of fixing this issue still.

Answer (score 1):

> If my application terminates too early, the transmission will be aborted and therefore fail since after the execution of flush() not all data has been sent yet.

The data is unbuffered so every write sends the data immediately.  In your case the `flush()` isn't doing anything.

DataOutputStream.flush()

```
public void flush() throws IOException {
    out.flush();
}
```

calls OutputStream.flush()

```
public void flush() throws IOException {
}
```

> Are there some "best practice" ways of assuring that all data has been sent before terminating my application?

The best way to ensure the data has been sent is to wait for a reply.  Have the other end send a message back to say it has received it and you can exit knowing the data has been received.

BTW When you have finished with a closeable resources, best practice is to close it.

Comment: Yes, I figured that the `flush()` was doing nothing also. Problem being that I don't know how to access the server code. I'm not sure if my socket already forces a tcp connection. Any tips on code I should try?

Comment: @user3764804 I think you need to understand the problem better as your write should send the data, and close() shouldn't be needed but it will ensure it's not needed any more.

Answer (score 0):

By the default `socket.close()` should cause graceful TCP connection closing. In that procedure TCP stack delivers unacknowledged data to the peer.

```
dataOutputStream.flush();
socket.close();
```

if you have set SO_LINGER to zero, then it won't work. 
Alternative is to use `socket.shutdownOutput()`:

```
dataOutputStream.flush();
socket.shutdownOutput();
```

Comment: Neither suggestion works and it still stops too early

Comment: Strange. Are you sure that TCP connection is still open when you call the flush()? and all the data is already written to dataOutputStream?

Comment: Yes. I tried calling `socket.close()` and `socket.shutdownOutput()` like you suggested after all `DataOutputStream` writes but both failed to wait till everything has been sent.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you found any fix other than 1 sec sleep ? @BullyWiiPlaza

Comment: Found the fix just set clientSocket.setSendBufferSize(1024) also make sure while receiving there you read in chunk of 1024 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Set `socket.setSendBufferSize(1024)` also make sure while receiving there you read in chunk of `1024` bytes.